# PostGIS function to connect geometry LINE together?

Tags: php, function, postgresql, postgis

(note: the_geom is a geometry value (TYPE: LINESTRING), in this case i random them for readability)

```
gid | kstart  | kend    | ctrl_sec_no | the_geom | the_sum_geom
626 | 238     | 239     | 120802      | 123456   | NULL
638 | 249     | 250     | 120802      | 234567   | NULL
4037| 239     | 249     | 120802      | 345678   | NULL
```

[Real Practice Description] just skip this for those who don't mind the purpose

> I would like to do 'this' (a set of queries from my past question, link
>   located on the end of this post) for every row in Table B (aka.
>   land_inventory). These two tables are related by 'ctrl_sec_no'
>   (aka. control section number of a road) which  means :: in ONE
>   ctrl_sec_no -- 120802 (in fact, it is a road which is equivalent to 3
>   geometry LINESTRINGs (the_geom) connected together, from kstart 238 (start at kilometre of 238) to kend 250)

[PostGIS question]

the question is how to connect this 3 lines {aka gid(626,638,4037) from the table} together and result in 'the_sum_geom' (initially NULL) by using PostGIS functions (whatever). after that we will use this 'the_sum_geom' to find the POINT on this geometry LINESTRING

([How calculate things from many tables by using a few queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211362/how-calculate-things-from-many-tables-by-using-a-few-queries)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [ST_Union](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Union.html), you need to use it with the aggregate form:

```
update mytable set the_sum_geom = 
ST_LineMerge( ( select ST_Union(the_geom) from mytable where ctrl_sec_no  = 120802 ) )
where ctrl_sec_no = 120802;
```

With [ST_LineMerge](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_LineMerge.html) you can convert from Multiline to LineString but there is  a caveat, if the multi line cant be merged it will return the multiline without any modification. See the [ST_LineMerge](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_LineMerge.html) docs to understand what ST_LineMerge can or can't do.

Comment: if we use ST_UNION the returned value will note be a LINESTRING, I want the result which be a linestring.